# Transparent Faced Sphere three.js

Tags: three.js, geometry, webgl, transparent

i'm trying to do a webGL transparent faced sphere with three.js

Test code available here : 
WebGL Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zbWMv/

I tryed many things, but i can't succed to bring it working.

I saw in renderer code that a sort is done for faces rendering, doing opaque first, then transparent in opposite order.

So i dont really know what to do next ...

Here is the same in canvas2D, which is working good.
Canvas 2D Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HHUaF/

Answer (score 0):

OK, il succeeded to find one solution using blending.

Thx to all guys that tried to help me on IRC !

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zbWMv/6/

It's not perfect shading, but its better than before ;)